# Jquery data picker: "Cannot read property 'setDate' of null"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

 jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('#input_1_24').datepicker({
   dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
   minDate: 0,
   onSelect: function (date) {
                var date2 = jQuery('#input_1_25').datepicker('getDate');
                date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
                jQuery('#input_1_25').datepicker('setDate', date2);
                //sets minDate to dt1 date + 1
    jQuery('#input_1_25').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date2);
   }
  }) 
  jQuery('#input_1_25').datepicker({
   dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    minDate: 0,
    onClose: function () {
                var dt1 = jQuery('#input_1_24').datepicker('getDate');
                console.log(dt1);
                var dt2 = jQuery('#input_1_25').datepicker('getDate');
                if (dt2 <= dt1) {
                    var minDate = jQuery('#input_1_25').datepicker('option', 'minDate');
                    jQuery('#input_1_25').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
                }
            }
        });
 });
});
```

When i run my page with 2 input type text with id= "input_1_24" and id="input_1_25" my dev console get this error:

[image]

I have no idea what it could be... can u help me?

Comment: Try debugging in the console: what does `jQuery('#input_1_25')` return? What is in `date2` (my best guess to this last one: undefined)

Comment: are you using jquery-ui date picker? to set date for datepicker you should use 
$( "#input_1_25" ).datepicker( "setDate", "10/12/2012" );

Comment: Why do you use this? 

var date2 = jQuery('#input_1_25').datepicker('getDate'); // date2 = "Thu Aug 16 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 ..." //

This will get the datepicker's date as string and this string not has setDate i guess.
Try to use  jQuery('#input_1_25').datepicker();

Comment: After telling me this I solved the mistake lol @LaurentS.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to change my code like that:

```js
 jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('#input_1_24').datepicker({
   dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
   minDate: 0,
   onSelect: function (date) {
    var date1 = jQuery('#input_1_24').datepicker('getDate');
    console.log(date1);
                date1.setDate(date1.getDate() + 1);
                jQuery('#input_1_25').datepicker('setDate', date1);
    jQuery('#input_1_25').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date1);
   }
  }) 
  jQuery('#input_1_25').datepicker({
   dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    minDate: 0,
    onClose: function () {
                var dt1 = jQuery('#input_1_24').datepicker('getDate');
                console.log(dt1);
                var dt2 = jQuery('#input_1_25').datepicker('getDate');
                if (dt2 <= dt1) {
                    var minDate = jQuery('#input_1_25').datepicker('option', 'minDate');
                    jQuery('#input_1_25').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
                }
            }
        });
 });
});
```

in this way it works correctly!

Answer (score 0):

You can do below way, see example.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( function() {
    $( "#input_1_24" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        minDate: 0,
        onSelect: function (date) {
            var date2 = $('#input_1_24').datepicker('getDate');
            date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
            $('#input_1_25').datepicker('setDate', date2);
            //sets minDate to dt1 date + 1
            $('#input_1_25').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date2);
        }
       }
    );
    $( "#input_1_25" ).datepicker({
   dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    minDate: 0,
    onClose: function () {
                var dt1 = $('#input_1_24').datepicker('getDate');
                console.log(dt1);
                var dt2 = $('#input_1_25').datepicker('getDate');
                if (dt2 <= dt1) {
                    var minDate = $('#input_1_25').datepicker('option', 'minDate');
                    $('#input_1_25').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
                }
            }
        }
     );
  } );
  </script>
</head>

<body>

    <p>Date1: <input type="text" id="input_1_24"></p>
    <p>Date2: <input type="text" id="input_1_25"></p>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var date2 = jQuery('#input_1_25').datepicker('getDate');
date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
jQuery('#input_1_25').datepicker('setDate', date2);
```

In this code the "date2" will contains string, and you can't call setDate on it.
Try this:

```
var date2 = jQuery('#input_1_25').datepicker();
jQuery('#input_1_25').datepicker('setDate', date2.datepicker("getDate") + 1));
```